# APP_FIRST_OPEN is not tracked on firebase dynamic link analytics for custom domains

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, dynamic-links

I have created multiple Firebase dynamic links with custom domain and my APP_FIRST_OPEN is always showing 0 (zero) in the analytics. Though the other paramaeters such as CLICK, REDIRECT, APP_INSTALL & APP_RE_OPEN is showing correct data.

Can anyone tell me the reason of this?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you manage to understand the cause of the problem?

Comment: Not yet.. Please let me know if you find something